# How to add images to a JButton when the images are in an array

Tags: java, arrays, image, swing

I am trying to add images to Jbuttons.  The images are in an array I created using a separate class.  Every attempt at adding the images have failed. I tried to turn them into ImageIcon and just add them as is and it is not working.  The first set of code is what I have used to create the buttons and add to the a JFrame.  My goal is to add event listeners so that when a button is pressed the button will show the image, a rectangle, or a rectangle with text

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ButtonTest extends JFrame{


    public ButtonTest(){

          JPanel panel = new JPanel();
          JButton[] b = new JButton[9];
          Image[] imgs = MyImageSplit.splitter("dog", 9);


          for (int i=0; i<b.length; i++){
             b[i]=new JButton();
             b[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

             panel.add(b[i]);
          }

        add(panel);  
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400,400);
      }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new ButtonTest();

        }
}
```

This code is what I used to split an image and add the smaller images to an array.

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class MyImageSplit {

    public static Image[] splitter (String filename, int numGroup){
        int rows=(int) Math.sqrt(numGroup);
        int cols=(int) Math.sqrt(numGroup);

        BufferedImage[] buffimage = new BufferedImage[rows*cols];
        Image[] images = new Image[rows*cols];

        try{
            File file = new File(filename + ".jpg"); //gets image from directory
            FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(f); //reads the image file



            //determines the width and height for each piece
            int pieceWidth=img.getWidth()/cols;
            int pieceHeight = img.getHeight()/rows;


            for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++) {
                    //Initialize the image array with image pieces
                    buffimage[x * rows + y] = new BufferedImage(pieceWidth, pieceHeight, img.getType());

                    // draws the image piece
                    Graphics2D gr = buffimage[x * rows + y].createGraphics();
                    gr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, pieceWidth, pieceHeight, pieceWidth * y, pieceHeight * x, pieceWidth * y + pieceWidth, pieceHeight * x + pieceHeight, null);
                    gr.dispose();
                }
            }

            for (int i =0; i < buffimage.length; i++){
                ImageIO.write(buffimage[i], "jpg", new File(filename + i + ".jpg"));

            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < rows*cols; i++){
            images[i] = (Image) buffimage[i];

        }

        return images;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        splitter("monkey", 9);
    }

}
```

[dog.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVaVl.jpg)

Comment: Have you check if the image is loaded correctly? Try simple code to use ImageIcon with JLabel on JFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you create the buttons but never set their images.

Add the following line to your main loop in `ButtonTest`:

`b[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgs[i]));`

Comment: I tried this before and it doesn't run.  This is what is in the console:

Comment: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@27973e9b
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at ButtonTest.<init>(ButtonTest.java:22)
 at ButtonTest.main(ButtonTest.java:35)

Comment: You are probably using an incorrect path to the image. Note that since you are using relative paths, the image has to be located in the current working directory.

Comment: Thank You.  This was correct.  I keep jumping to different project folders and I did not have the images in the folder I was currently working on

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to add pictures to each of button. Add this to your `for-loop`:

```
for (int i=0; i<b.length; i++){
    b[i]=new JButton();
    b[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
    b[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgs[i]));
    panel.add(b[i]);
}
```

Moreover I recommend you to change the `JButton` prefered size since the picture doesnt fit them.

```
b[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
```

And the size of `JFrame` as well.

```
setSize(800,400);
```

---

Edit: Use the `.png` image file extension to keep the colors correctly. `.jpg` causes the loss the some of colors simply said. Compare:

**dog.jpg**

[image]

**dog.png**

[image]

Comment: the image is already imported using the MyImageSplit class.  That class returns an array of the images.  I need to pull the images from the array so why do I need to input the file again?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, I have forgotten that variable. I've edited my answer. Please check the `for-loop` part again. Also check if the path of image is correct.

Comment: Thank You.  This was correct.  I keep jumping to different project folders and I did not have the images in the folder I was currently working on.